# Python array counter

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

The assignment is

> Write a function `collect_sims(nsim,N,D,p=0.5,nmax=10000)` that runs your `run_sim` function `nsim` times (with parameters `N`, `D`, `p`) and returns a numpy array of length `nmax` giving the number of times that the simulation took a specified number of steps to stop.
>
> For example, suppose `nsim` was 8 and successive runs of `run_sim` gave you 3,4,4,3,6,5,4,4.
> You would tabulate this as “two 3s, four 4s, one 5, one 6, zero 7s, zero 8s …”

The function this function calls is

```
def run_sim(N=20, D=6, p=0.5, itmax=5000):

counter = N
sum = 0
i = 0

while counter != 0:

    if i>itmax:
        raise RuntimeError

    c = np.random.randint(1,D+1,1)[0] # method returns an array with 1 value
    coin = np.random.binomial(1,p,1)[0] # if =1 is heads, =0 is tails
    print(i,"|",c,"|",counter)

    if coin ==1:
        if (counter + c)>N:
            i+=1
        else:
            i=+0
            counter = counter +c
    elif coin ==0:
        print("coint == 0: counter - c:", counter - c)
        if(counter - c)<0:
            i+=1
        else:
            i+=1
            counter = counter -c
            print("coint ==0: counter:", counter)
        if counter==0:
            break
return(i)

print(run_sim(N=20, D=6, p=0.5,itmax=500))

print(run_sim(N=20, D=12, p=0.5, itmax=500))
```

I wrote:

```
def collect_sims(nsim, N, D, p=0.5, nmax=10000):
    run_sim(N=N, D=D, p=0.5, itmax=5000)
    a=np.zeros(nmax)
    a.reshape(nsim,2)
    for i in range (nsim):
        a[run_sim(N,D,p),2] += 1
    return(a)
```

It isn't giving me an error but it also isn't returning or printing anything when I run it, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show the code that actually calls this function. It would also be useful to see `run_sum`

Comment: Again, please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.